# Analyzing crash dump file from Windows 2003 R2 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003, server-crashes, bsod

My Windows 2003 R2 SP2 server crashes about once a month. I analyzed the crash dump but can't really figure out what it means. Any help is appreciated....

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64 Copyright
>   (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading Dump File [C:\Users\noam\Downloads\MEMORY.DMP] Kernel Summary
>   Dump File: Only kernel address space is available
>
> Symbol search path is:
>   SRV*C:\Windows\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
>   Executable search path is:  Windows Server 2003 Kernel Version 3790
>   (Service Pack 2) MP (4 procs) Free x64 Product: Server, suite:
>   TerminalServer SingleUserTS Built by: 3790.srv03_sp2_qfe.120821-0338
>   Machine Name: Kernel base = 0xfffff800`01000000 PsLoadedModuleList =
>   0xfffff800`011d8280 Debug session time: Thu Mar 21 10:48:04.909 2013
>   (UTC - 4:00) System Uptime: 24 days 13:36:09.953 Loading Kernel
>   Symbols
>   ...............................................................
>   .................................................. Loading User
>   Symbols PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 000007ff`fffdf018).  Type ".hh
>   dbgerr001" for details Loading unloaded module list ....
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.
>
> BugCheck 50, {fffffadf28a13000, 0, fffff800012c532e, 0}
>
> *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for sptd.sys Probably caused by : sptd.sys ( sptd+5fe75 )
>
> ### Followup: MachineOwner
>
> 3: kd> !analyze -v
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50) Invalid system memory was referenced.
>   This cannot be protected by try-except, it must be protected by a
>   Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it is pointing at
>   freed memory. Arguments: Arg1: fffffadf28a13000, memory referenced.
>   Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
>   Arg3: fffff800012c532e, If non-zero, the instruction address which
>   referenced the bad memory     address. Arg4: 0000000000000000, (reserved)
>
> ### Debugging Details:
>
> READ_ADDRESS:  fffffadf28a13000
>
> FAULTING_IP:  nt!PspGetSetContextInternal+203 fffff800`012c532e
>   488b58f8        mov     rbx,qword ptr [rax-8]
>
> MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  0
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  0x50
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe
>
> CURRENT_IRQL:  1
>
> TRAP_FRAME:  fffffadf1fb32710 -- (.trap 0xfffffadf1fb32710) NOTE: The
>   trap frame does not contain all registers. Some register values may be
>   zeroed or incorrect. rax=fffffadf28a13007 rbx=0000000000000000
>   rcx=0000000000000001 rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000
>   rdi=0000000000000000 rip=fffff800012c532e rsp=fffffadf1fb328a0
>   rbp=fffffadf228d0b10  r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000
>   r10=0000000000000000 r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000
>   r13=0000000000000000 r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000 iopl=0 
>   nv up ei ng nz ac pe nc nt!PspGetSetContextInternal+0x203:
>   fffff800`012c532e 488b58f8        mov     rbx,qword ptr [rax-8]
>   ds:fffffadf`28a12fff=???????????????? Resetting default scope
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800010a69dd to fffff8000102eb90
>
> STACK_TEXT:   fffffadf`1fb32638 fffff800`010a69dd : 00000000`00000050
>   fffffadf`28a13000 00000000`00000000 fffffadf`1fb32710 :
>   nt!KeBugCheckEx fffffadf`1fb32640 fffff800`0102d759 :
>   00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
>   00000000`00000000 : nt!MmAccessFault+0xa1f fffffadf`1fb32710
>   fffff800`012c532e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
>   fffffadf`1fb33c70 fffffadf`228d05c0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x119
>   fffffadf`1fb328a0 fffff800`010425bb : fffffadf`35821040
>   fffffadf`1fb32fa0 fffffadf`35821088 00000000`00000000 :
>   nt!PspGetSetContextInternal+0x203 fffffadf`1fb32df0 fffff800`01028081
>   : fffffadf`385ce018 fffff800`00810310 00000000`00000001
>   fffffadf`385ce018 : nt!PspGetSetContextSpecialApc+0xab
>   fffffadf`1fb32f00 fffff800`01027c8d : fffffadf`358210b8
>   00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffffadf`35c06558 :
>   nt!KiDeliverApc+0x215 fffffadf`1fb32fa0 fffffadf`28b33e75 :
>   fffffadf`28b3b91c fffffadf`35c06558 fffffadf`35c06440
>   00000000`00000000 : nt!KiApcInterrupt+0xdd fffffadf`1fb33138
>   fffffadf`28b3b91c : fffffadf`35c06558 fffffadf`35c06440
>   00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : sptd+0x5fe75 fffffadf`1fb33140
>   fffffadf`38ddd2de : fffffadf`1fb33240 fffff800`0102550f
>   00000000`00000000 fffffadf`1fb33248 : sptd+0x6791c fffffadf`1fb33220
>   fffffadf`1fb33240 : fffff800`0102550f 00000000`00000000
>   fffffadf`1fb33248 fffffadf`385cc050 : 0xfffffadf`38ddd2de
>   fffffadf`1fb33228 fffff800`0102550f : 00000000`00000000
>   fffffadf`1fb33248 fffffadf`385cc050 00000000`00000000 :
>   0xfffffadf`1fb33240 fffffadf`1fb33230 fffff800`011ad8fd :
>   00011000`00000000 fffffadf`385cc050 00000001`80392000
>   00000000`00000002 : nt!IopfCompleteRequest+0x9c8 fffffadf`1fb332a0
>   fffffadf`358a8ca0 : 00000000`00001000 0000000a`1f1e5000
>   fffffadf`385d3040 fffffadf`289da2b7 : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x67b
>   fffffadf`1fb33360 00000000`00001000 : 0000000a`1f1e5000
>   fffffadf`385d3040 fffffadf`289da2b7 fffffadf`385d4cb0 :
>   0xfffffadf`358a8ca0 fffffadf`1fb33368 0000000a`1f1e5000 :
>   fffffadf`385d3040 fffffadf`289da2b7 fffffadf`385d4cb0
>   fffffadf`1fb33860 : 0x1000 fffffadf`1fb33370 fffffadf`385d3040 :
>   fffffadf`289da2b7 fffffadf`385d4cb0 fffffadf`1fb33860
>   fffffadf`358a8f68 : 0x0000000a`1f1e5000 fffffadf`1fb33378
>   fffffadf`289da2b7 : fffffadf`385d4cb0 fffffadf`1fb33860
>   fffffadf`358a8f68 fffffadf`358a8ca0 : 0xfffffadf`385d3040
>   fffffadf`1fb33380 fffffadf`28943f92 : fffffadf`358a8ca0
>   fffffadf`37eee640 fffffadf`358a8f68 fffffadf`385d3190 :
>   ftdisk!FtDiskReadWrite+0x1e7 fffffadf`1fb333d0 fffffadf`2874f361 :
>   00000000`00000000 fffffadf`2676915c fffffadf`37b811c8
>   fffffadf`358a8ca0 : volsnap!VolSnapRead+0xa2 fffffadf`1fb33410
>   fffffadf`2875e582 : fffffadf`00000000 fffffadf`00001000
>   fffffadf`37eee640 fffffadf`00000000 : Ntfs!NtfsPagingFileIo+0x202
>   fffffadf`1fb33510 fffffadf`28751e2e : fffffadf`1fb336a0
>   fffffadf`358a8ca0 fffffadf`1fb33601 fffffadf`1fb336e0 :
>   Ntfs!NtfsCommonRead+0x4d3 fffffadf`1fb336a0 2444c7c8`8b48d233 :
>   44c74873`46635328 15ff0000`00982024 762d8b48`00002f0d
>   8b481445`ff00008d : Ntfs!NtfsFsdRead+0x262 fffffadf`289da3a7
>   44c74873`46635328 : 15ff0000`00982024 762d8b48`00002f0d
>   8b481445`ff00008d 4800002f`0a15ffcd : 0x2444c7c8`8b48d233
>   fffffadf`289da3af 15ff0000`00982024 : 762d8b48`00002f0d
>   8b481445`ff00008d 4800002f`0a15ffcd 8b1875f0`8b48c085 :
>   0x44c74873`46635328 fffffadf`289da3b7 762d8b48`00002f0d :
>   8b481445`ff00008d 4800002f`0a15ffcd 8b1875f0`8b48c085
>   4d8b2845`8b442c55 : 0x15ff0000`00982024 fffffadf`289da3bf
>   8b481445`ff00008d : 4800002f`0a15ffcd 8b1875f0`8b48c085
>   4d8b2845`8b442c55 483055ff`1845ff24 : 0x762d8b48`00002f0d
>   fffffadf`289da3c7 4800002f`0a15ffcd : 8b1875f0`8b48c085
>   4d8b2845`8b442c55 483055ff`1845ff24 c62474f0`8b48c085 :
>   0x8b481445`ff00008d fffffadf`289da3cf 8b1875f0`8b48c085 :
>   4d8b2845`8b442c55 483055ff`1845ff24 c62474f0`8b48c085
>   3807058d`48017a46 : 0x4800002f`0a15ffcd fffffadf`289da3d7
>   4d8b2845`8b442c55 : 483055ff`1845ff24 c62474f0`8b48c085
>   3807058d`48017a46 46c60078`46c60000 : 0x8b1875f0`8b48c085
>   fffffadf`289da3df 483055ff`1845ff24 : c62474f0`8b48c085
>   3807058d`48017a46 46c60078`46c60000 c7480042`46c60079 :
>   0x4d8b2845`8b442c55 fffffadf`289da3e7 c62474f0`8b48c085 :
>   3807058d`48017a46 46c60078`46c60000 c7480042`46c60079
>   89480000`00001046 : 0x483055ff`1845ff24 fffffadf`289da3ef
>   3807058d`48017a46 : 46c60078`46c60000 c7480042`46c60079
>   89480000`00001046 ff184b8d`486beb06 : 0xc62474f0`8b48c085
>   fffffadf`289da3f7 46c60078`46c60000 : c7480042`46c60079
>   89480000`00001046 ff184b8d`486beb06 a8bb8000`002ea415 :
>   0x3807058d`48017a46 fffffadf`289da3ff c7480042`46c60079 :
>   89480000`00001046 ff184b8d`486beb06 a8bb8000`002ea415
>   8b483d74`00000000 : 0x46c60078`46c60000 fffffadf`289da407
>   89480000`00001046 : ff184b8d`486beb06 a8bb8000`002ea415
>   8b483d74`00000000 878d4c00`0000b897 : 0xc7480042`46c60079
>   fffffadf`289da40f ff184b8d`486beb06 : a8bb8000`002ea415
>   8b483d74`00000000 878d4c00`0000b897 988b8d4c`000000a8 :
>   0x89480000`00001046 fffffadf`289da417 a8bb8000`002ea415 :
>   8b483d74`00000000 878d4c00`0000b897 988b8d4c`000000a8
>   4901034a`80000000 : 0xff184b8d`486beb06 fffffadf`289da41f
>   8b483d74`00000000 : 878d4c00`0000b897 988b8d4c`000000a8
>   4901034a`80000000 89490889`4d08518b : 0xa8bb8000`002ea415
>   fffffadf`289da427 878d4c00`0000b897 : 988b8d4c`000000a8
>   4901034a`80000000 89490889`4d08518b 4b8d4802`894c0850 :
>   0x8b483d74`00000000 fffffadf`289da42f 988b8d4c`000000a8 :
>   4901034a`80000000 89490889`4d08518b 4b8d4802`894c0850
>   0841894d`d0b60f18 : 0x878d4c00`0000b897 fffffadf`289da437
>   4901034a`80000000 : 89490889`4d08518b 4b8d4802`894c0850
>   0841894d`d0b60f18 abe90000`2cdb15ff : 0x988b8d4c`000000a8
>   fffffadf`289da43f 89490889`4d08518b : 4b8d4802`894c0850
>   0841894d`d0b60f18 abe90000`2cdb15ff 0090b38b`48000000 :
>   0x4901034a`80000000 fffffadf`289da447 4b8d4802`894c0850 :
>   0841894d`d0b60f18 abe90000`2cdb15ff 0090b38b`48000000
>   b60f184b`8d480000 : 0x89490889`4d08518b fffffadf`289da44f
>   0841894d`d0b60f18 : abe90000`2cdb15ff 0090b38b`48000000
>   b60f184b`8d480000 01000000`a883c6d0 : 0x4b8d4802`894c0850
>   fffffadf`289da457 abe90000`2cdb15ff : 0090b38b`48000000
>   b60f184b`8d480000 01000000`a883c6d0 8b4c0000`2cbb15ff :
>   0x0841894d`d0b60f18 fffffadf`289da45f 0090b38b`48000000 :
>   b60f184b`8d480000 01000000`a883c6d0 8b4c0000`2cbb15ff
>   478b4800`0000b887 : 0xabe90000`2cdb15ff fffffadf`289da467
>   b60f184b`8d480000 : 01000000`a883c6d0 8b4c0000`2cbb15ff
>   478b4800`0000b887 46894810`7e894808 : 0x0090b38b`48000000
>   fffffadf`289da46f 01000000`a883c6d0 : 8b4c0000`2cbb15ff
>   478b4800`0000b887 46894810`7e894808 508d4918`408b4908 :
>   0xb60f184b`8d480000 fffffadf`289da477 8b4c0000`2cbb15ff :
>   478b4800`0000b887 46894810`7e894808 508d4918`408b4908
>   4c028b20`46894808 : 0x01000000`a883c6d0 fffffadf`289da47f
>   478b4800`0000b887 : 46894810`7e894808 508d4918`408b4908
>   4c028b20`46894808 8d481846`89306689 : 0x8b4c0000`2cbb15ff
>   fffffadf`289da487 46894810`7e894808 : 508d4918`408b4908
>   4c028b20`46894808 8d481846`89306689 46894800`024b1405 :
>   0x478b4800`0000b887 fffffadf`289da48f 508d4918`408b4908 :
>   4c028b20`46894808 8d481846`89306689 46894800`024b1405
>   00000098`878b4828 : 0x46894810`7e894808 fffffadf`289da497
>   4c028b20`46894808 : 8d481846`89306689 46894800`024b1405
>   00000098`878b4828 40b60f41`38468948 : 0x508d4918`408b4908
>   fffffadf`289da49f 8d481846`89306689 : 46894800`024b1405
>   00000098`878b4828 40b60f41`38468948 03388041`40468802 :
>   0x4c028b20`46894808 fffffadf`289da4a7 46894800`024b1405 :
>   00000098`878b4828 40b60f41`38468948 03388041`40468802
>   0f000000`80be8948 : 0x8d481846`89306689 fffffadf`289da4af
>   00000098`878b4828 : 40b60f41`38468948 03388041`40468802
>   0f000000`80be8948 0000889e`8948c094 : 0x46894800`024b1405
>   fffffadf`289da4b7 40b60f41`38468948 : 03388041`40468802
>   0f000000`80be8948 0000889e`8948c094 0164bb80`41468800 :
>   0x00000098`878b4828 fffffadf`289da4bf 03388041`40468802 :
>   0f000000`80be8948 0000889e`8948c094 0164bb80`41468800
>   438b4811`74000000 : 0x40b60f41`38468948 fffffadf`289da4c7
>   0f000000`80be8948 : 0000889e`8948c094 0164bb80`41468800
>   438b4811`74000000 00000170`8b8b4808 : 0x03388041`40468802
>   fffffadf`289da4cf 0000889e`8948c094 : 0164bb80`41468800
>   438b4811`74000000 00000170`8b8b4808 8b480000`011090ff :
>   0x0f000000`80be8948 fffffadf`289da4d7 0164bb80`41468800 :
>   438b4811`74000000 00000170`8b8b4808 8b480000`011090ff
>   d68b4800`0000b887 : 0x0000889e`8948c094 fffffadf`289da4df
>   438b4811`74000000 : 00000170`8b8b4808 8b480000`011090ff
>   d68b4800`0000b887 304e8b48`01034880 : 0x0164bb80`41468800
>   fffffadf`289da4e7 00000170`8b8b4808 : 8b480000`011090ff
>   d68b4800`0000b887 304e8b48`01034880 8b483050`ff018b48 :
>   0x438b4811`74000000 fffffadf`289da4ef 8b480000`011090ff :
>   d68b4800`0000b887 304e8b48`01034880 8b483050`ff018b48
>   4024648b`4c58246c : 0x00000170`8b8b4808 fffffadf`289da4f7
>   d68b4800`0000b887 : 304e8b48`01034880 8b483050`ff018b48
>   4024648b`4c58246c 7c8b4860`24748b48 : 0x8b480000`011090ff
>   fffffadf`289da4ff 304e8b48`01034880 : 8b483050`ff018b48
>   4024648b`4c58246c 7c8b4860`24748b48 b850245c`8b486824 :
>   0xd68b4800`0000b887 fffffadf`289da507 8b483050`ff018b48 :
>   4024648b`4c58246c 7c8b4860`24748b48 b850245c`8b486824
>   48c48348`00000103 : 0x304e8b48`01034880 fffffadf`289da50f
>   4024648b`4c58246c : 7c8b4860`24748b48 b850245c`8b486824
>   48c48348`00000103 cccccccc`ccccccc3 : 0x8b483050`ff018b48
>   fffffadf`289da517 7c8b4860`24748b48 : b850245c`8b486824
>   48c48348`00000103 cccccccc`ccccccc3 cccccccc`cccccccc :
>   0x4024648b`4c58246c fffffadf`289da51f b850245c`8b486824 :
>   48c48348`00000103 cccccccc`ccccccc3 cccccccc`cccccccc
>   828b4838`ec8348cc : 0x7c8b4860`24748b48 fffffadf`289da527
>   48c48348`00000103 : cccccccc`ccccccc3 cccccccc`cccccccc
>   828b4838`ec8348cc 246c8948`000000b8 : 0xb850245c`8b486824
>   fffffadf`289da52f cccccccc`ccccccc3 : cccccccc`cccccccc
>   828b4838`ec8348cc 246c8948`000000b8 10788318`6a8b4848 :
>   0x48c48348`00000103 fffffadf`289da537 cccccccc`cccccccc :
>   828b4838`ec8348cc 246c8948`000000b8 10788318`6a8b4848
>   c000000d`b80f7318 : 0xcccccccc`ccccccc3 fffffadf`289da53f
>   828b4838`ec8348cc : 246c8948`000000b8 10788318`6a8b4848
>   c000000d`b80f7318 c4834848`246c8b48 : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
>   fffffadf`289da547 246c8948`000000b8 : 10788318`6a8b4848
>   c000000d`b80f7318 c4834848`246c8b48 4840245c`8948c338 :
>   0x828b4838`ec8348cc
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  kb
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  sptd+5fe75 fffffadf`28b33e75 0000            add
>   byte ptr [rax],al
>
> SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  7
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  sptd+5fe75
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: sptd
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  sptd.sys
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4611064e
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_sptd+5fe75
>
> BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_sptd+5fe75
>
> ### Followup: MachineOwner
>
> 3: kd> lmvm sptd start             end                 module name
>   fffffadf`28ad4000 fffffadf`28bf2000   sptd       (no symbols)
>
> ```
> Loaded symbol image file: sptd.sys
> Image path: sptd.sys
> Image name: sptd.sys
> Timestamp:        Mon Apr 02 09:34:06 2007 (4611064E)
> CheckSum:         000D960A
> ImageSize:        0011E000
> Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
> ```

Comment: Do you have Daemon Tools or Alcohol 120% or ImgBurn installed? If so... start by uninstalling that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not the best OS debugger, but here's what I see:

`PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50) Invalid system memory was referenced.`

What often causes this is a "use after free" condition where memory is freed, and then a thread references it as if it were still allocated.  When a user-mode program does this, it usually just ends up crashing that program.  But when a kernel-mode component, such as a driver, does this, it causes a bug check. It can also be caused when a thread attempts to write to an address that is marked as read-only. But because argument two of the error code specified that the fault occured during a read operation, we can eliminate that possibility.

Other things can cause this bug check as well, such as faulty hardware, and cosmic rays flipping bits in your RAM.  But for the sake of discussion we'll disregard those possibilities as well.

If you look at the stack text - this stands out to me:

`ExFreePoolWithTag+0x67b fffffadf1fb33360`

That function freed pool memory, which is in kernel space.  I'm not positive that it freed the memory that was later referenced that caused the machine to crash, but I'm highly suspicious of it. It is typically drivers that allocate and deallocate pool memory. The people who write drivers have to be *extremely* careful about allocating and deallocating memory, because if you don't do it *perfectly*, you either cause a memory leak or you crash the machine.

If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see the parameters of your bug check code:

```
Parameter       Description
---------------------------    
1   Memory address referenced    
2   0: Read operation   1: Write operation    
3   Address that referenced memory (if known)    
4   Reserved
```

Windbg identified sptd.sys as a probable cause of the crash. I'm guessing Windbg figured that sptd.sys is the culprit because it happened to be loaded in the address that was found in argument 3 of the bug chuck code. (But I could be wrong about that. I'm not sure how Windbg derives that information.) The information is not guaranteed to be accurate in any case, but stpd.sys appears to be a non-Microsoft driver related to CD/DVD burning software like Daemon Tools and Alcohol 120%.

I would definitely start by either upgrading or uninstalling that software.

Edit: Looks like you can find updated versions of sptd.sys here: http://www.disc-tools.com/download/sptd

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to find that sptd.sys is related to those programs before posting here and I can assure you that neither of them is installed on the machine. It's an Exchange server with Blackberry server integration. That's it. What else could have caused this?

Comment: OK, forget the CD/DVD burning software. What version of sptd.sys is on your machine?

Comment: how do i check the version?

Comment: Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` and check the properties of the sptd.sys file. If it's lower than 1.83 or so, I would upgrade it. It seems pretty apparent from the crash dump that it is what is causing your crashes.

Comment: there is no version number when i check the properties...just the regular file attributes

Comment: Then hash it. Version 1.83 32 bit has an SHA-1 hash of ca126da33bc4bb828a01ea69ed498798b88332da. Version 1.83 64 bit has an SHA-1 hash of e9dc4c94c18a1812a1a71bcb33be9a42d0abdb7c. The driver vendor's website is http://www.duplexsecure.com/.  Their driver is crashing your machine. Uninstall it, or upgrade it.